# Why does my terminal have funny characters for the date field? Looks like Russian?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, osx-lion

Strangely my terminal has funny characters in the date area that look like Russian. Does anyone know why it displays these characters?

[image]

(I'm running Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: what are you trying to view?

Comment: Yes, this is Russian ))))

Comment: Why is Russian output in contradiction with having Mac OS X Lion? Is it a specifically non-Russian OS?

Comment: Maybe your locale is somehow set to Russian? Does it change to English if you issue the command `LC_ALL=C ls -l`?

Comment: Russians go )))

Comment: LC_ALL=C ls -l works for me. Is there any way to make this my default? How do I change my locale back?

Comment: You have been hacked by the Russians!

Comment: Anyone hav ea solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a line in my .bash_profile that was setting my LANG to russian. Must have been from a bad copy and paste job from somewhere!